# How to replace Link component behavior with History in React-Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history

In my app I have

```js
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={DashboardRoute} exact={true} />
        <Route path="/patients/:id" component={PatientRoute} />
        <Redirect to='/' />
      </Switch>
```

Then inside **PatientRoute** I have another Switch with dynamic routes.

```js
<Switch >
  {panes.map(pane => {
     return <Route path={`/patients/:id/${pane.to}`}>
        {pane.render()}
     </Route>
  })}
</Switch>
```

I've built a Tab like component called **RouteTab** that uses **Link** to redirect to a sub patient route.

```js
<div className="TabButtons">
  {panes.map((p, index) => <Link key={p.to} to={p.to} label={p.menuItem}/>)}
</div>
```

At this point everthing works fine. However My **RouteTab** components has a responsive behavior, when Mobile it uses a Select to display the menu of items. To simulate **Link** behavior I am using **history.push**, the url changes but the page doesn't re-render.

```js
<Select
   value={panes[activeTab].menuItem}
   onChange={(e, data) => {
      const value = data.value;
      const newTabIndex = panes.findIndex(p => p.menuItem === value)
      const newTab = panes[newTabIndex]

      history.replace(newTab.to) //<--- Here
   }}
   options={panes.map(p => ({
      key: p.menuItem,
      value: p.menuItem,
      text: p.menuItem,
   }))}></Select>
```

Here is a complete example https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-care-router-45t5w

Comment: Wrap it inside `withRouter` (HOC). Use `this.props.history.push(/route)` to get the job done.

Comment: I am already using useHistory hook. Is it not the same here?

Comment: can you show where you are using `useHistory`?

Comment: It Is in the codesandbox link up above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another `<Router>` in routeTab. Doing so seems to create two different router instances and that's why the history.push didn't work.

Here's a working sample that I forked from the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-care-router-2m3oh

I disabled the responsiveness to test the dropdown within the same view.

I got the idea from this example in the docs here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery